# In a CQRS system, how should I show the user that their request has been received?

Tags: nservicebus, msmq, cqrs

I'm trying to decouple some of the bits of our big-ball-of-mud architecture, and identified several boundaries that are obvious candidates for using CQRS to provide a more resilient and scalable solution.

Typical example: when a customer places an order, at the moment we block their thread whilst the order is submitted for payment, approved by the sales system, etc, etc.

This can all be handled asynchronously - allowing us to accept and queue orders whilst the payment processing system is unavailable, etc. - but I'm not sure how I should manage the UI data for the customer.

In other words - they place an order. Their order goes in a queue. If they log back into their account five seconds later and click "review orders" - what happens?

- If I draw it from the central repo (or from a cache that's updated based on that repo), then the user won't see their order and will probably try and place it again - or phone us and panic.
- If I draw it from a local database, then I have the overhead of maintaining *another* database of orders - which will need to be synchronised in a load-balanced environment, and seems to undermine a lot of the advantages of CQRS.

I want to do this in lots of places - and not all of them are actions as significant as confirming an order; in some cases it's as simple as a customer changing a phone number or something - so they're not all cases where I can just say "thanks a lot, we'll send you a confirmation e-mail" - because sending confirmation e-mails for every modification to a record strikes me as a little excessive.

Any patterns or solutions I should look at to help with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Something worth considering is a 'user' inbox: a place in your app the user can consult 'in-progress' commands at. You could also 'push' notifications back to the user's UI when he has already moved onto another screen, but still resides in your app. This might also be an option when the user logs back on.
- Another option could be faking the synchronous experience, i.e. wait around and do polling while in the background everything happens asynchronously. Granted, this might involve including timeouts as well, but I'd argue that those are embraced in today's synchronous processing as well.
- On top of all this, you may want to both inform and solicit feedback from your end users about how they experience your app and its behavior.
- Regardless what anybody tells you, if you want to handle this elegantly, it will take some effort on your part.

Answer (score 3):

The best thing to do is lie!

The user should have no idea that their transaction is in fact a little like Schrödinger's cat, either dead or alive. From their perspective the transaction was a success, because you just indicate to them that it was successful and queue the job away for offline processing.

Because the vast majority of transactions are successful you can then handle those that are not with an appropriate compensationary mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

**Insignificant cases, like modification of some record:**

1. Send the user to a confirmation page telling him something around the lines of "Thanks, your input is being processed. What do you want to do next?" and a couple of links.
2. If you absolutely have to send the user back to the edited record or a list thereof, in non-distributed systems we're probably talking about milliseconds until the read store has been updated. As long as it takes longer to redirect the user to the new page, from the user's POV everything's fine.
3. If in some cases the user actually doesn't see his update "immediately", he might call user support. They tell him to hit F5. What? It's there now? Great! Guess what he does next time before reaching for the phone.

**Significant cases like offline order processing:**

There might be an implicit concept of a *Received Order* or *Pending Order* in your domain. If you make this concept explicit, you can present the user with accurate information.

"Thank you very much! Your order has been received an we'll keep you updated once it has been shipped. [Click here] to see a list of your pending orders..."

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest thing, doing nothing, can often be good enough. If user changes phone number, and the system processes this command in 1-2s, it is a good chance user has not had the opportunity to see old data in-between this operation.

If that is not satisfactory, and your user must absolutely know that his request was fulfilled, your UI can subscribe to domain events. Once the command is executed successfully, your UI gets notification and can inform the user. There are various ways you could do this in UI. You could simply block until the success notification arrives. Or you can say "we received your request", and once you get confirmation, show the notification window "your request was fulfilled" somewhere in the corner.